# setting fitsSystemWindows to true on DrawerLayout on pre Lollipop issue

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've added a `NavigationDrawer` to an existing app.

Setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on the `DrawerLayout` seems to work fine on android v21 and higher. But on v20 and lower it surprisingly makes my entire screen draw as if there's no status-bar, which causes half of my toolbar to be hidden underneath it.

I can fix it by setting the **fitsSystemWindows** to false, but

A) this is the exact opposite of what I expected to happen. Shouldn't setting fitsSystemWindows to true push the drawing beneath the status bar?

B) this causes the `NavigationView` header layout in v21 and above to be somewhat hidden underneath the status bar...

Any help?